# VBA VLookup by Column Name

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to perform a VLookup where the column of the data I will be pulling can vary. How can I search for the column name instead of having to give a fixed column number?

`Application.VLookup(.Cells(row, 1).value, Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:Z" & lastRow_Sheet1), 4, 0)`

`Application.VLookup(.Cells(row, 1).value, Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:Z" & lastRow_Sheet1), COLUMNNAME, 0)`

I'm trying to get a MATCH function working here but am having no luck:

`Application.VLookup(.Cells(row, 1).value, Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:Z" & lastRow_Sheet1), WorksheetFunction.Match("Column Name", "A1:Z1", 0), 0)`

Edit: Solution here

`Application.VLookup(.Cells(row, 1).value, Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:Z" & lastRow_Sheet1), WorksheetFunction.Match("Column Name", Range("A1:Z1"), 0), 0)`

Comment: How is `MATCH` not working?

Comment: I receive 1004 Run-time error: Unable to get the Match property of the WorksheetFunction class. I don't see why this is, I can see the column name I'm searching for is in the range I've specified.

Comment: You haven't specified a range in `MATCH` - `"A1:Z1"` is a string.

Comment: @norie Thanks for that, on another note, this appears to only work when I'm actively on the tab, if I'm on another tab I receive the same error

Comment: No problem, by the way I would suggest you do the `MATCH` separately before the lookup. That would give you an opportunity to avoid errors if the column name isn't found for some reason.

Comment: You could easily use the `Range.Find` method to locate the column header.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### `Match` instead of `VLookup`

You could use the following function to get the column number:

```vb
Function getTableColumnNumber( _
    ByVal HeaderRange As Range, _
    ByVal HeaderTitle As String) _
As Long
    If Not HeaderRange Is Nothing Then
        If Len(HeaderTitle) > 0 Then
            Dim cIndex As Variant
            cIndex = Application.Match(HeaderTitle, HeaderRange, 0)
            If IsNumeric(cIndex) Then
                getTableColumnNumber = cIndex
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Function
```

Note that the column number is the 'n-th' column of the header range which is not necessarily the 'n-th' column of the worksheet (e.g. if the range starts in column `C`).

**An Example**

[image]

- On the left is the Source Worksheet (`Sheet1`) which usually contains unique data (green column).
- On the right is the Destination Worksheet (`Sheet2`) where the yellow column is initially blank. It illustrates a case where `VLookup` cannot work because the return values (yellow column) are to the left of the lookup values (green column).

---

- This is a case where all the columns are defined by their headers.
- Adjust the values in the constants section.
- `s` - Source, `d` - Destination, `l` - Lookup, `m` - Match.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub matchValues()

    Const sName As String = "Sheet1"
    Const slHeader As String = "ID"
    Const smHeader As String = "Value"
    Const sCols As String = "A:Z"
    Const sFirst As Long = 1
    
    Const dName As String = "Sheet2"
    Const dlHeader As String = "ID"
    Const dmHeader As String = "Value"
    Const dCols As String = "A:Z"
    Const dFirst As String = 1

    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    Dim slrg As Range, smrg As Range
    With wb.Worksheets(sName)
        Dim shrg As Range: Set shrg = .Columns(sCols).Rows(sFirst)
        Dim slCol As Long: slCol = getTableColumnNumber(shrg, slHeader)
        If slCol = 0 Then Exit Sub
        Dim smCol As Long: smCol = getTableColumnNumber(shrg, smHeader)
        If smCol = 0 Then Exit Sub
        Dim srg As Range: Set srg = getDataRange(shrg)
        Set slrg = srg.Columns(slCol)
        Set smrg = srg.Columns(smCol)
    End With
    
    Dim drg As Range
    With wb.Worksheets(dName)
        Dim dhrg As Range: Set dhrg = .Columns(dCols).Rows(dFirst)
        Dim dlCol As Long: dlCol = getTableColumnNumber(dhrg, dlHeader)
        If dlCol = 0 Then Exit Sub
        Dim dmCol As Long: dmCol = getTableColumnNumber(dhrg, dmHeader)
        If dmCol = 0 Then Exit Sub
        Set drg = getDataRange(dhrg)
    End With
    
    Dim dCell As Range
    Dim cIndex As Variant
    For Each dCell In drg.Columns(dlCol).Cells
        cIndex = Application.Match(dCell.Value, slrg, 0)
        If IsNumeric(cIndex) Then
            dCell.EntireRow.Columns(dmCol).Value = smrg.Cells(cIndex).Value
        Else
            dCell.EntireRow.Columns(dmCol).Value = "Not Found"
        End If
    Next dCell

End Sub

Function getTableColumnNumber( _
    ByVal HeaderRange As Range, _
    ByVal HeaderTitle As String) _
As Long
    If Not HeaderRange Is Nothing Then
        If Len(HeaderTitle) > 0 Then
            Dim cIndex As Variant
            cIndex = Application.Match(HeaderTitle, HeaderRange, 0)
            If IsNumeric(cIndex) Then
                getTableColumnNumber = cIndex
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Function

Function getDataRange( _
    ByVal HeaderRange As Range) _
As Range
    If Not HeaderRange Is Nothing Then
        With HeaderRange.Offset(1)
            Dim lCell As Range
            Set lCell = .Resize(.Worksheet.Rows.Count - .Row + 1) _
                .Find("*", , xlFormulas, , xlByRows, xlPrevious)
            If Not lCell Is Nothing Then
                Set getDataRange = .Resize(lCell.Row - .Row + 1)
            End If
        End With
    End If
End Function
```